# how to use linearGradient animate in CSS3 keyframe?

Tags: css, svg, css-animations, linear-gradients

Is it possible to apply `@keyframes` in **SVG** instead of using `linearGradient` `animate` ?

```html
<svg id="battery" width="110px" height="88px" viewBox="0 0 110 88" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns">
  <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
    <g id="Group" fill="#EAEAEA">
      <path d="M104,30.2724875 C104.164709,30.2576038 104.331485,30.25 104.5,30.25 C107.537566,30.25 110,32.7220822 110,35.7458573 L110,53.1708094 C110,56.2060875 107.531385,58.6666667 104.5,58.6666667 C104.331455,58.6666667 104.164681,58.6590557 104,58.6441617 L104,82.0033234 C104,85.3151964 101.311488,88 97.9970362,88 L6.0029638,88 C2.68761844,88 0,85.3182852 0,82.0033234 L0,5.99667663 C0,2.68480358 2.68851188,0 6.0029638,0 L97.9970362,0 C101.312382,0 104,2.68171476 104,5.99667663 L104,30.2724875 L104,30.2724875 Z M5,10.991014 C5,7.68226832 7.68678744,5 11.0051618,5 L92.9948382,5 C96.3113975,5 99,7.68493655 99,10.991014 L99,77.008986 C99,80.3177317 96.3132126,83 92.9948382,83 L11.0051618,83 C7.68860254,83 5,80.3150634 5,77.008986 L5,10.991014 Z"
      id="loading-frame" fill="url(#loading)"></path>
      <linearGradient id="loading" x1="0">
        <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#fdc22d"></stop>
        <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#eaeaea"></stop>
        <animate attributeName="x1" fill="freeze" dur="3s" from="-100%" to="100%" />
      </linearGradient>
    </g>
    <path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" d="M65,21 L41,43 L53,47 L46.5,67 L70,44 L58.5,39.5 L65,21 Z" class="thunder" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: No....you would need javascript to do that.

Comment: @Paulie_D It think that is also should be fine, I need to modify animation without touching `html` file

Comment: Then you need to [edit] your question, add the appropriate tags, and as you know, it is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. . I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=animate+svg+gradient

Comment: @Paulie_D the reason why question like this is I was looking for solution in css and there is no enough knowledge how to apply css animation in to svg elements

Comment: There is no CSS solution.

Comment: @MuhammedAthimannil: You are animating a SVG attribute `x1` and I don't think there is a CSS equivalent for this.

Comment: Is there any reason you're looking for a CSS3 solution specifically?

Comment: @Petrus Rex this animation is part various elements CSS3 animation, JavaScript solution also should be fine